# Sorting JSON data by date in HUGO

Tags: hugo

I have the following data structure working in a HUGO site
Data in local appearances.json file:

```
{
    "events":[ {
        "name": "title three",
        "date": "7/02/2022",
        "url": "http://some.com"
    },
    {
       "name": "title one",
       "date": "5/01/2022",
       "url": "http://some.com"
   },
    {
        "name": "title two",
        "date": "7/01/2022",
        "url": "http://some.com"
    }]

}
```

Partial page:

```
 <div class="row listrecent">           
    {{ range  .Site.Data.appearances.events }}
          {{- partial "list-partials/appearancebox.html" . -}} 
     {{end}}  
</div>
```

output:
[image: Picture of output to screen]

However, I would like to sort the contents of the array by "date", preferably with the newest event at the top - i.e the first block visible should be "title three"

I have tried various sort methods with some success but I cannot seem to combine sorting by date and converting the stringified date.

I could ensure the JSON is in the correct order but that seems fragile to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the end was this:

```
    {{ $events := slice }}
    {{ range .Site.Data.appearances.events }}
    {{ $event := . }}
    {{ $parsedEvent := dict }}
    {{ range $k, $v := $event }}
    {{ if eq $k "date" }}
    {{ $parsedEvent = merge $parsedEvent (dict $k (time $v)) }}
    {{ else }}
    {{ $parsedEvent = merge $parsedEvent (dict $k $v) }}
    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
    {{ $events = $events | append $parsedEvent }}
    {{ end }}
    <div class="row listrecent">
    {{ range sort $events "date" "desc" }}

   
        {{ if (.date.After now) }}
        {{- partial "list-partials/appearancebox.html" . -}}

        {{ end }}
    {{end}}
</div>
```

If anyone has a cleaner way then I am all ears!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your json is "events.json", then go for the code below:

```
<ul>
{{ range sort $json.events "date" "desc" }}
    <li>
        <b>
            {{ .name }}
        </b>
        <br>            
        {{ .date }}
    </li>
{{ end }}
</ul>
```

The above solution is working check my [branch repo](https://github.com/cromozooom/playground-hugo/tree/q69753662)

Comment: Yeah this didn't work - it was one of the ways that I had tried already.

Comment: @LaylaCodesIt it's strange that it worked for me ...
do you have a repo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not near my dev set-up, so this will be psuedo code and concepts, but:

1. https://gohugo.io/functions/range/#readout <- not very detailed.
2. https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/#readout <- Much more data.

So, something like:
Authors: {{ range sort .Site.Params.authors }}{{ .firstName }} {{ end }}
(example given in link 2 above).

So concept/psuedo, I believe:
{{ range sort .Site.Data.etc.etc. "date" }}

This would sort by ascending (again, not sure the final output for a date field, also due to the fact I believe you have date as a string, which I understand, it's json, but meaning, it's not going to give you expected output. so you might have to convert that field to a date object or data sortable concept as opposed to a string.
https://gohugo.io/functions/format/#use-local-and-utc
Might be of assistance for that.

Again, not near my compu/dev setup, but the above should work. The key being the sort command.